# PHP File upload & Edit

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a website and i'm making a content management system for the website. I need to be upload a .txt file and then be able to edit that file inside the website. so far I have this:

```
<?php
        $myFile = fopen("welcome-content.txt", 'r');
        while (($buffer = fgets($myFile)) !== false) {
            echo "<p>";
            echo $buffer;
            echo "</p>";
        }
        fclose($myFile);
    ?>
```

This is able to upload the file, but I have to have the file name as "welcome-content.txt", I want to be able too select a file from the File Explorer, upload it, and then be able to edit it. Am I right in thinking I need a HTML Form in order to select the file? But as far as anything else I'm not sure where to go from there.

Any tips?

Comment: Yeap - HTML form or upload via JavaScript/AJAX. Either way, you need something client-side.

Answer (score 1):

Generate html form to choose file for upload:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="test_php.php">
   <input id="image-file" name="image-file" type="file" />
   <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

Write php code to handle your upload and modify file:

```
<?php

if ( !isset($_FILES['image-file']['error']) || is_array($_FILES['image-file']['error']) ) 
{
    throw new RuntimeException('Invalid parameters.');
}

// Check $_FILES['image-file']['error'] value.
switch ($_FILES['image-file']['error']) 
{
    case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
        break;
    case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
        throw new RuntimeException('No file sent.');
    case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
    case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
        throw new RuntimeException('Exceeded filesize limit.');
    default:
        throw new RuntimeException('Unknown errors.');
}

// Check filesize here. 
if ($_FILES['image-file']['size'] > 1000000) 
{
    throw new RuntimeException('Exceeded filesize limit.');
}
$filename = $_FILES['image-file']['name'];

echo "Filename is $filename <br>";

//Add new line
$f = fopen($filename,"a"); // Append mode
fwrite($f, "Added new line\n");
fclose($f);

echo "After modify file content is: <br>";
echo file_get_contents( $filename );
```